# Converting a list of dictionaries into a new dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to parse some html table content and I have a payload that looks like this:

```
"payload": [
    {
      "Cell #1": "Origin",
      "Cell #2": "Destination",
      "Cell #3": "Miles",
      "Cell #4": "Rate"
    },
    {
      "Cell #1": "Pampa, TX",
      "Cell #2": "Sallisaw, OK",
      "Cell #3": "207",
      "Cell #4": "$725"
    },
    {
      "Cell #1": "Pampa, TX",
      "Cell #2": "Sallisaw, OK",
      "Cell #3": "207",
      "Cell #4": "$725"
    },
    {
      "Cell #1": "Pampa, TX",
      "Cell #2": "Atoka, OK",
      "Cell #3": "176",
      "Cell #4": "$625"
    },
    {
      "Cell #1": "Pampa, TX",
      "Cell #2": "Wichita, KS",
      "Cell #3": "460",
      "Cell #4": "$1,150"
    }
  ]
```

You can see that the first dictionary in this list is the table headers. Then every item after is ordered by its corresponding header.

I am trying to make it look like this:

```
        [
            {
                "Origin": "Pampa, TX",
                "Destination": "Sallisaw, OK",
                "Miles": "207",
                "Rate": "$725"
            },
        ]
```

The catch is that the first list item which is the headers could change to add/remove "columns" so it would need to be versatile.

**What I'm Trying**
First I believe that each dict should be converted to a list of their values:

```
rows = []

for row in rows:
   rows.append(row.values)
```

This outputs list of lists:

```
rows = [['Origin', 'Destination', 'Miles', 'Rate']), ['Pampa, TX', 'Sallisaw, OK', '207', '$725'], ['Pampa, TX', 'Sallisaw, OK', '207', '$725'], ['Pampa, TX', 'Atoka, OK', '176', '$625'], ['Pampa, TX', 'Wichita, KS', '460', '$1,150']]
```

normally if I was converting this and I knew the headers prior to receiving the payload, I would then be able to build the dictionary based on the preset headers.

Something like:

```
        for r in rows:
            converted_row = {
                "Origin": r[0],
                "Destination": r[1],
                "Miles": r[2],
                "Rate": r[3]
            }
```

But that doesn't solve for the part that the columns are dynamic. Also assuming that the ordering always matches. I have a feeling there is a more dynamic way to do this with list comprehension.

Comment: So you want the values from the first dictionary in the list to be the keys for the dictionaries in the result and the values from the rest of the dictionaries in the list to be the values for the dictionaries in the result. This is assuming all dictionaries in the list have the same number of elements, but for different lists, the number of elements in the dictionaries may vary. Seems straightforward, what part is giving you problems? Please share your code.

Comment: do you want the object like example object , for every other cell values?

Comment: Added more context with my thoughts on solving this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `dicts` is your list of dictionaries and you are using at least Python 3.7 such that we can assume a deterministic order of dict items, then you can issue:

```
>>> keys = dicts[0].values()
>>> [dict(zip(keys, d.values())) for d in dicts[1:]]
[{'Origin': 'Pampa, TX', 'Destination': 'Sallisaw, OK', 'Miles': '207', 'Rate': '$725'}, 
 {'Origin': 'Pampa, TX', 'Destination': 'Sallisaw, OK', 'Miles': '207', 'Rate': '$725'},
 {'Origin': 'Pampa, TX', 'Destination': 'Atoka, OK', 'Miles': '176', 'Rate': '$625'},
 {'Origin': 'Pampa, TX', 'Destination': 'Wichita, KS', 'Miles': '460', 'Rate': '$1,150'}]
```

Answer (score 4):

assuming you have this list stored in  a variable named `payload` ...

you can just grab the headers from the first entry and use them as keys for the values in the remaining entries, and turn them into a list of dictionaries using a list comprehension

based on the OP I'm assuming you want a list of similar dictionaries for all entries:

```
headers = payload[0].values()

output = [dict(zip(headers,entry.values())) for entry in payload[1:]]
```

output:

```
[{'Destination': 'Sallisaw, OK',
  'Miles': '207',
  'Origin': 'Pampa, TX',
  'Rate': '$725'},
 {'Destination': 'Sallisaw, OK',
  'Miles': '207',
  'Origin': 'Pampa, TX',
  'Rate': '$725'},
 {'Destination': 'Atoka, OK',
  'Miles': '176',
  'Origin': 'Pampa, TX',
  'Rate': '$625'},
 {'Destination': 'Wichita, KS',
  'Miles': '460',
  'Origin': 'Pampa, TX',
  'Rate': '$1,150'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this with very easy to understand code

```
#Declare an empty list to record the desired keys
keys=[]

#Filling the keys (dynamic and can be used for any other object)
for i in p[0].values():
    keys.append(i)

#Declare an empty ans list 
ans=[]   

#Loop over the given payload values from 2nd value to last
for i in p[1:]:

    #making the current ith dict values as a list
    ls=list(i.values())

    #declare an empty dictionary to catch the current iteration values
    dict={}

    #filling the current iteration dict values to the keys[]
    for j in range(len(ls)):
        dict[keys[j]]=ls[j]

    #finally appending the current iteration temp dict to final ans list
    ans.append(dict)

return ans
```

Comment: I'm assuming it's because of the work around nature of appending to empty lists and multiple and even nested for loops to do something that could really be done in one line using more efficient built in methods/functions

Comment: yes it can be done in one line, but is my answer wrong? I wanted to give the very basic code without using complex function @DerekEden

Comment: I never said it was wrong .. but I would argue that this is more complicated than the other answers

Comment: I didn't downvote, but even though this may seem less complex to you, it actually is much more difficult to understand when looking at, whereas the other solutions are very straightforward

Comment: if you time these and yours is faster I'd be happy to upvote :) but for larger lists/dicts this would certainly not be